# When you upload news on your website, how to make added news go top not down?

Tags: php

I have a website with admin panel, there I add Image and description of the and everything works fine when you go to events page everything that is new uploaded appears top and old goes bot, but on images it doesn't work, I mean Everything new Goes to bottom not to top like 1 2 3 4 not 4 3 2 1.

Source code:

```
<?php 
$eventsQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC ");
?>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Artists</th>
<th></th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while($event = $eventsQuery->fetch_assoc()): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $event['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo substr($event['description'], 0, 70); ?>...</td>
        <td><?php echo $event['date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $event['artists']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="<?php echo $app_host; ?>/admin/?page=editevent&id=<?php echo $event['id']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $app_host; ?>/admin/?page=removeevent&id=<?php echo $event['id']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></a>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: cms or system do you use?

Comment: Xampp i'm running on localhost now

Comment: So are you claiming that MySQL is ignoring your `ORDER BY` clause entirely? Since sorting the `ID` descending would reverse the order for you as required.

Comment: @ThimoFranken `ASC` => `1 2 3 4`, `DESC` => `4 3 2 1`.